# MATLAB to Python Code Conversion - imclose() issue

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I'm manually converting MATLAB code to Python and I'm stuck at one line.

MATLAB code:

```
cashew_BW = threshad(cashew_GRAY(:,:,1),T);
cashew_BW = ~cashew_BW;
cashew_BW = imclose(cashew_BW, true(5));
cashew_BW = ~cashew_BW
```

Python converted code:

```
T = 112
se = [[1,1,1,1,1]]*5
cashew_BW = pymorph.threshad(cashew_GRAY, T, f2=None)
cashew_BW = np.logical_not(cashew_BW)
cashew_BW = 1*(cashew_BW)
cashew_BW = pymorph.close(cashew_BW, se)
cashew_BW = np.logical_not(cashew_BW)
cashew_BW = 1*(cashew_BW)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check1.py", line 22, in <module>
    cashew_BW = pymorph.close(cashew_BW, se)
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorph-0.96-py2.7.egg/pymorph/mmorph.py", line 1303, in close
    return erode(dilate(f,Bc ),Bc )
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorph-0.96-py2.7.egg/pymorph/mmorph.py", line 1580, in dilate
    x,v = mat2set(B)
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorph-0.96-py2.7.egg/pymorph/mmorph.py", line 4392, in mat2set
    if len(A.shape) == 1: A = A[newaxis,:]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The way matrices work in MATLAB is similar to `numpy` arrays but python lists are different. Coming from MATLAB, it is not obvious so I'd suggest reading a bit more about python lists. For example, the line

```
se = [[1,1,1,1,1]]*5
```

won't return `[5,5,5,5,5]` but instead creates

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

The default behaviour with a python list is to create 5 times the list. 
The error you see is because you are passing `se`, a python list (`len(a)` to get size), when `pymorph.close` expects a [numpy array](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#what-advantages-do-numpy-arrays-offer-over-nested-python-lists) (`a.shape` to get shape/size). You should always convert to numpy arrays to get consistent behaviour with MATLAB, in your case,

```
se = 5*np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
```

will give `[5,5,5,5,5]` and should avoid the error in `pymorph.close` as se is of type numpy array.

Comment: I used just np.array([1,1,1,1,1]) to check and I got an error: `too many indices for array`

Comment: I assume error is after passing `se` to `pymorph.close`?  From the docs it should be of form `{3x3 cross}` so maybe try something like `se=pymorph.secross(r=1)` to see if this works...